# table borders in the pdf are of uneven color

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo

I am generating a pdf using java and doing the formatting with XSL ..I have few tables that are being generated in the pdf . Problem is the border of the tables are not of even darkness . somepart of the line is dark and some part is light .

How can I correct this formatting .

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some samples so that we can reproduce the problem. Without that information, it is quite hard to find out where the issue is... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to set the table properties like color ,font ,alignment is to set those in the `<xsl:attribute-set>` and then later call this using `<use-attribute-sets>`.This way you would not have to set the properties at every table cell ,just need to call the attribute set .

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a table border might look lighter depending on your Zoom level. If you zoom in and the borders are displaying weird it must be your code to display borders.
Check all of your border settings for:

- table
- header row
- body row
- footer row

All of these can be set with different border-top, border-bottom, border-left, and border-right thicknesses.

Answer (score 0):

Print the document. If they are all the same then it is the viewer and resolution of the monitor that is the issue. Many FO renderers use polygons to represent borders so that corners are mitered as they should be for different colors or sizes. Some PDF viewers (especially Reader on Windows) cannot handle thin polygons when the screen representation is but one or two pixels.

Likely there is nothing wrong with the file,  it is only the view application.